# Adapt the display of a form to the screen resolution (Delphi XE8)

Tags: alignment, screen-resolution, delphi-xe8

I'm having trouble solving the problem of adapting the display of a form according to the resolution of the screen.

I wrote my code in a 15 inch laptop, I'm using 1366X 768 resolution, The form fills the screen perfectly, and the display is as expected
[image: See Photo 1]

but when I open my application in another computer with a larger screen (1920x1080 resolution), the shape takes up the whole screen, but the display of objects is not as expected, [image: see photo 2], there is too much space..

I am looking for a way to adapt the appearance of the form according to the screen, i.e. to make the display look like photo 1 whatever the screen resolution

I tried to play on the properties of the form (Align,Anchors Autosize..), but it did not work

Comment: Looks like you need to play around with the `Align` and `Anchors` properties of your controls so they stretch as the parent Form resizes.

Comment: I found a way with  .scaleby..
but I have a problem with two components which do not change size:  stringgrid and toolbar, I have played with the Anchors and Align properties, without result.